# opencv contrib repo Installation

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using linux and want to install opencv contrib repo to include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp" file. I have read the readme file from the link : https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib , but still can't understand how to use the commands in the terminal . Can anyone help ? I have installed opencv in home (~/opencv) and the folder opencv_contrib-master in Downloads.

Comment: I got it working compiling from source on MacOS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48042674/1602316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I had to uninstall the library and install it again, like described in this link  : http://embedonix.com/articles/image-processing/installing-opencv-3-1-0-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Just clone opencv_contrib to the any directory you like then build it as:

1. git clone (opencv_contrib)
2. cd opencv (main directory) and mkdir build
3. cd build
4. Here u have to provide the linkage to the
       opencv_contrib. I used the following command.

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH../opencv_contrib/modules ..

Comment: I still get errors in the terminal such as The binary directory

    /home/giorgos/opencv/modules/datasets/.datasets

  is already used to build a source directory.  It cannot be used to build
  source directory

    /home/giorgos/opencv/opencv_contrib-master/modules/datasets

  Specify a unique binary directory name.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules) 

Which shows up for every module several times.. ANy ideas ?

Comment: Maybe i should use cmake during the installation of opencv for both ? I mean delete opencv and re install it including in cmake command both 

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .. 

AND


  -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH../opencv_contrib/modules ..

 ??

Comment: Did u try to delete ur build directory and then do the cmake as i stated above. When you change your cmake commands, please clean the directory off as previous cmakes should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Cut short the best way is to do

sudo apt-get install cmake-gui

go to the root of opencv folder
mkdir build
cmake-gui ..
then put the path of the opencv_extra modules

build it and install it and enjoy.