# How do I install opencv_contrib on a linux system that already has opencv installed?

Tags: python, opencv

I have already built and installed openCV on my linux system and have been using it for several weeks. Now, I am trying to use `cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()`. I am under the impression that I need to install opencv_contrib for this module. However, the fix given here, [opencv contrib repo Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377955/opencv-contrib-repo-installation), requires a complete rebuild of openCV. How can I build opencv_contrib without completely rebuilding openCV?

Comment: You can't, you need to rebuild it with contrib support.

Comment: Dmitrii Z. I was afraid you'd say that